# What does the following declaration mean?

Tags: c

```
struct abcd poly[] = {
               {"Inside","Outside"},
               {"Outside","Inside"},
               };
```

What does the above declaration mean?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to tell if you posted the definition of `struct abcd`.

Comment: what is `abcd` ? Where did you declare that type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an array of 2 structs

```
struct abcd
{
    char s1[20]; // or *s1
    char s2[20]; // or *s2
};

int main()
{ 
    abcd s[]=  { {"a","b"}, {"c","d"},  };
    cout << s[0].s1<< endl;
    cout << s[0].s2 << endl;
    cout << s[1].s1<< endl;
    cout << s[1].s2 << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

That will create an array of 2 `struct abcd` named poly. If the struct looks like this then str1 and str2 would be set to "Inside" and "Outside".

```
struct abcd
{
    const char *str1;
    const char *str2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a two-element array of structs. The literals inside the inner braces initialize the structs' fields.